# polar equation related question and im really stuck

Tags: calculus

Show that the polar equation of the line $x+ \sqrt{3} \cdot y=2$ can be expressed as $r= \sec \left(\theta-\frac{\pi}{3} \right)$.

Answer (score 1):

Put $x=r\cos\theta,y=r\sin\theta$ and use $\cos(A-B)=\cos A\cos B+\sin A\sin B$

to get $r\cos\left(\theta-\frac\pi3\right)=1$